# How does the max() function work in Jython?

Tags: python, list, jython

I need this function to tell me the longest sequence of positive numbers in a list.

```
def longestSequencePos(nums):
    index = 0
    list = []
    integ = 0

    for obj in nums:
      if obj > 0:
        index = index +1
      else: 
        list.append(index)
        index = 0
    return max(list)
```

list should contain all of the lengths of the sequences of positives, but the max function is not working.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Never use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: Debugging:  `print list`, or rather `print better_name_than_list`

Comment: Please fix your title to reflect your **actual** question.  The title is misleading.  Perhaps "how do I use max() to find the longest sequence of positive numbers in a list." or something that reflects the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

you are not appending anything to your list when you are exiting the loop and nums only has positive integers, you will need to do something like:

```
def longestSequencePos(nums): 
    index = 0
    list = []
    integ = 0 

    for obj in nums:
        if obj > 0:
            index = index +1
        else: 
            list.append(index)
            index = 0

    list.append(index)

    return max(list)
```

which will append the last count of index if the list is empty at the end of the loop.

also, you have called your `list`, well, `list`, which is actually a constructor for a `list`, although this is not the problem it is something to watch out for as a `do not do`

Comment: Index should be added to the list at the end of the loop even if it isn't empty, otherwise it would miss any case where the longest sequence is at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a list to do this:

```
count = maxc = 0
for obj in nums:
    if obj > 0:
        count += 1
    else:
        maxc = max(count, maxc)
        count = 0
maxc = max(count, maxc)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you aren't adding index to the list when nums is exhausted, so if the list ends in the longest sequence, it won't return the correct value:

```
def longestSequencePos(nums):
    index = 0
    list = []
    integ = 0

    for obj in nums:
      if obj > 0:
        index = index +1
      else: 
        list.append(index)
        index = 0
    list.append(index)
    return max(list)
```

This fixed version works for me in the normal python interpreter. I haven't tried it on jython.